# Replacing comma with a dot in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ and want to replace a comma coming in between numbers with a dot.
Like in below text file:

00:00:00,166 --> 00:00:03,999
In this section we will look at

should be like below:

00:00:00.166 --> 00:00:03.999
In this section we will look at

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

Find:

```
(?<=\d),(?=\d)
```

Replace with:

```
.
```

Here is a screenshot. Make sure you select **Regular Expression** radio button (pointed to by arrow).
    [image]
Regex:

```
(?<=\d) - Positive look behind for a digit char
(?=\d) - Positive look ahead for a digit char
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/iw1XsV/1

Comment: maybe replace by `\1.\2`

Comment: @baddger964 Those are not capture groups. It's look ahead and look behind.

Comment: @MYGz wouldyou elaborate on ?<= and ?= in your answer?

Comment: oh yes sorry my bad

Comment: @MYGz Thanks. I added a screenshot to your answer showing reg ex radio button on the replace dialog, in case the some one new to notepad++ and does not know they need to select reg ex.

Comment: @HappyTown Oh thanks for that :)

Comment: Thank you MYGz. It still has some issue. It is searching and stopping at correct position but it is not replacing it with a dot. Rather it moves to the next when I click on Replace.

Comment: With Replace All command it is working fine.

Comment: @Neeraj When you click on Replace, It replaces and moves to next. Check the previous match, it would have been replaced by `.`

Comment: Yeah there's something not right with this. I'm also using this for timestamps, but the other way around. It just replaces everything between those numbers. The semicolon gets replaced as well, replaced the semicolon with a dollar sign, the dollar sign gets replaced as well. So yeah, not quite right.
This one works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152588/replacing-comma-by-dot-only-in-numbers-in-a-texteditor-using-search-and-replace