# Replacing comma by dot only in numbers in a texteditor using search and replace function

Tags: regex, text-editor, editplus

i got a table as txt.file with all the variables beeing seperated by ;.

Lets say i got 3 Variables: ID, Size and Comment.

My Data could look something like this:

```
1;1.5;hello. how are you?  
2;2.5;a comment.  
3;2.1;another comment.
```

Now i would like to replace the comma-sign from dot to comma.
If i use the standard search and replace function in my text-editor it will change all `.` to `,` without any problem. But i want to change only those `.` to `,` which are surrounded by numbers left side and right side.
`1.5` should be changed to `1,5` but `hello. how are you?` should not be changed to `hello, how are you?`

I found a regular expression for searching only dots surroundet by numbers:

```
[0-9][\\.][0-9]
```

Now i would like to replace those surroundet dots, but unfortunately it doesn't work yet. When replacing `[0-9][\\.][0-9]` by `,`, `1.5` is changed to `,` only instead of `1,5`.

Is there any nice way to use search and replace from a texteditor to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your text editor?

Comment: Replacing ([\d])\.([\d]) with $1,$2 should work.Where group 1 is the number before '.' and group 2 is the number after '.'. 
Make sure you have regex option chosen in the search-replace editor.
Or to make your example work (without \d), it should be: ([0-9])\.([0-9]) => $1,$2

Comment: Thanks for youre suggestions. 
Im using EditPlus. 
I've tried replacing ([0-9])\.([0-9]) by $1,$2 which ends up with 1.5 beeing replaced by $1,$2. 

It looks like the groups are not working. Maybe its a different sign than $ in EditPlus or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EditPlus does not support lookbehinds, so you need to use groups.

```
(\d)\.(\d)
```

Substitution: `\1,\2`

- `()` Capturing group
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `\1` `\2` Capturing group 1. and group 2.

[image]